# How to store a Task in a dictionary for later execution in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, dynamic

I'm trying to store a Task in a dictionary for later execution with no success:

```
Dictionary<string, Task<object>> router = new Dictionary<string, Task<object>();
router["xyz"] = functionToLaterExec

async Task<string> functionToLaterExec()
{
    return await Task.FromResult("Success!");
}
```

If I declare the function as

```
string functionToExec()
```

Then I can do:

```
router["xyz"] = new Task<string>(functionToExec);
```

But I need the function to be async. And don't know how to invoke it. I've tryed:

```
var t = router["xyz"];
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(await t);
```

with no success.

Thanks.

Comment: You really should not store `Task` or `Task<T>` objects to be run later, you should be storing `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>` objects. Also, there is never a reason to do `new Task(...` unless you are writing a task schedueller, You should only work with "hot tasks".

Comment: Thank you very much @ScottChamberlain. That did it. Since you were the first one responding, if you want me to accept your answer, please post one. If you don't, I will accept Servy's.

Comment: Go accept Servy's

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to be able to start an asynchronous operation later then you don't want to store a `Task`, you'll want to store a `Func<Task>` (or, in your case, a `Func<Task<string>>`, so that, when you want to start the operation, you can invoke the function, producing a `Task` that represents its completion.

Comment: @aledpardo If you want to store something that can start a task later, you store a `Func<Task>`, and then you execute the function when you want to start it, giving you a `Task`.